# Oracle SQL retrieve Column Names with table names from execution plan as a Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, explain

I need retrieve from execution plan column names with table name. I can see explain plan and see projection column  but i can not retrieve from this part because it is not table. Is there any table which contain executin plan in any format for example XML or Relation format?
[image]

Additonaly :  "SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY())" it is not help because this give result in one column.

Comment: Have you tried [`DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_PLAN()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-FDE553FD-2099-47B6-A1F8-83BFFDCF5662)? It seems that setting the `type` parameter might give you what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

As the DBMS_XPLAN functions only return CLOBs you will need to parse the fields yourself - for example like this:

```
SELECT to_number(regexp_substr(plan_table_output, '[^|]+', 1, 1)) id,
       regexp_substr(plan_table_output, '[^|]+', 1, 2) operation,
       regexp_substr(plan_table_output, '[^|]+', 1, 3) name,
       regexp_substr(plan_table_output, '[^|]+', 1, 4) "ROWS",
       regexp_substr(plan_table_output, '[^|]+', 1, 5) bytes,
       regexp_substr(plan_table_output, '[^|]+', 1, 6) cost
  from table(dbms_xplan.display)
 where instr(plan_table_output, '|') = 1
   and plan_table_output <> '| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|';
```